# mount returns non-zero exit code 64

Tags: python, centos, subprocess, centos7

when running "mount -a" on a production system (Centos 7), I'm getting return code 64

```
try:
    subprocess.check_call(["mount", "-a"])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    raise Exception("Failed to run mount command. error:%s", str(e))
```

The following are logs:

```
raise Exception("Failed to run mount command. error:%s", str(e))
Exception: ('Failed to run mount command. error:%s', "Command '['mount', '-a']' returned non-zero exit status 64")
```

What does exit code 64 mean?

Comment: Check `man mount` for the return codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means some filesystems failed to mount but others succeeded.

From [mount(8) manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man8/mount.8.html):

## RETURN CODES

```
   mount has the following return codes (the bits can be ORed):

   0      success

   1      incorrect invocation or permissions

   2      system error (out of memory, cannot fork, no more loop devices)

   4      internal mount bug

   8      user interrupt

   16     problems writing or locking /etc/mtab

   32     mount failure

   64     some mount succeeded

   The command mount -a returns 0 (all succeeded), 32 (all failed), or 64 (some failed,  some
   succeeded).
```